# Limits of 2 variable functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How would I prove that if $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is a function such that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y) = L$$

and for every $y_0 \in \mathbb R$

$$ \lim_{x\to a} f(x,y_0) = L'_{y_0}$$

and for every $x_0 \in \mathbb R$

$$ \lim_{y\to b} f(x_0,y) = L''_{x_0}$$

then

$$
\lim_{x\to a}\left(\lim_{y\to b} f(x,y)\right)  = \lim_{y\to b}\left(\lim_{x\to a} f(x,y)\right) = L$$

Answer (score 12):

You cannot prove that the two-variable limit equals the iterated limits even if they both exist, since the two-variable limit may fail to exist even if both iterated limits exists and are equal. For example, take $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, with $a=b=0$. The iterated limits both exist:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{x^2} = 0,$$
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right) = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{0}{y^2} = 0.$$
But the limit does not exist as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. If you approach $(0,0)$ along the line $y=x$ you get the limit as $x\to 0$ of $\frac{x^2}{2x^2}$, which goes to $\frac{1}{2}$, not $0$. So the two-variable limit does not exist, even though the two iterated limits both exist and are equal.

If you assume that the two-sided limit exists and is equal to $L$, and then you want to prove that the iterated limits will therefore both exist and be equal, then you might have a better shot. Start by thinking about the definitions.

**Added later:** And then look at Robin Chapman's example to see that it does not quite work out. So you don't get implications either way.

Comment: I edited my question, does it make more sense now or is this still false?

Comment: If the limit exists, then the two iterated limits should exist and be equal to $L$. Think about the definition of limit; find a small open rectangle around (a,b) where all points are sufficiently close and work from there to show the iterated limits also exist and are equal to what you want.

Answer (score 11):

This is a rejoinder to Arturo's comment that if the two-variable limit
exists then both iterated limits exist.
Define
$$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
(x^2+y^2)\sin(1/x+1/y)&\textrm{if $xy\ne0$,}\\
0&\textrm{if $xy=0$.}
\end{array}\right.$$
Then certainly $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$; that is
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=0.$$
But for any nonzero $x$,
$$\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)$$
doesn't exist (the function is wildly oscillatory for $y$ near zero). So
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y)\right)$$
is meaningless.