# Exchange the order of the two limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Suppose both limits exist, when is it true that
$$\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{y\to b} f(x,y) = \lim_{y\to b}\lim_{x\to a} f(x,y) ?$$
and further when is it true that these two limits are equal to $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y)$, assuming the latter exists?

Since we are not dealing with sequences of functions, most convergence theorems don't work here.

Comment: @copper.hat Not quite. See this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/6543).

Comment: @GitGud: Thanks for catching that, will delete misleading comment. Nice counterexample.

Comment: @copper.hat I've thought about this before and I've seen similar question being asked. I've looked in the books. I still haven't found a good treatment of this topic and I couldn't do it myself. I want to know the answer.

Comment: @GitGud: I should have known better! I remember being confused by this over 30 years ago when I started real analysis in earnest.

Comment: Hasty answer: this holds whether one of the limits exists uniformly with respect to the other variable. This is explained well on Lang's textbook *Undergraduate analysis*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preliminary analysis

WLOG $a=b=0$. Now assume both limits exist. Thus define
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y)&=\nu\\
\lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,y)&=\omega
\end{align}
$$
Then there exists a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ small enough for it to be possible for $(x,y)$ in this neighbourhood to define $f_y,f_x$ as
$$
f_y(x)=
\begin{cases}
\nu&&&\text{for }x=0\\
\text{  }\\
\lim_{y\to 0}f(x,y)&&&\text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
and a similar definition of $f_x$ where $f_x(0)=\omega$ and $f_x(y)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,y)$ for $y\neq 0$. These functions are defined by pointwise limits and may have nothing to do with $f(x,y)$ along the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$. They are both continuous at $0$ by our assumption. They do not have to be continuous anywhere else. For now that is all we know.

### Suppose the limits are unequal

Assume $\nu\neq\omega$. Since $f_y(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ we know that for $x\neq 0$ small enough we can have $f_y(x)$ closer to $\nu$ than $\varepsilon=0.2|\nu-\omega|$. Fixing such $x$, choosing $y$'s small enough will ensure in addition to that that $f(x,y)$ is closer to $f_y(x)$ than this $\varepsilon$ too. This can be obtained for all $(x,y)$ in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of the line $x=0$ near $(0,0)$. So in this neighbourhood we have $f(x,y)$ closer to $\nu$ than $0.4|\nu-\omega|$ except for possibly on the line itself. Similarly we may find a neighbourhood of the line $y=0$ near $(0,0)$ where $f(x,y)$ is closer to $\omega$ than $0.4|\nu-\omega|$. Both these neighbourhoods will have a non-empty intersection with any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$.

**Conclusion:** In the case of $\nu\neq\omega$ we can always find function values further appart than $0.2|\nu-\omega|$. This means that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ cannot exist.

### Suppose the limits are equal

**The limit may still not exist**

Now if $\nu=\omega$ we can still not be sure that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ will exist. One example is given in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6483/94971) to the question linked to by [Git Gud](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55235/git-gud) in the comment section. As another example, one could simply choose any two continuous functions $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ with $f_1(0,0)=\nu$ and $f_2(0,0)\neq\nu$ and define
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\text{anything}&&&\text{at }(0,0)\\
f_2(x,y)&&&\text{for }|x/y|\in[0.5,2]\\
f_1(x,y)&&&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
[image: Plot of (x,y) regions illustrating the above example]

The the limit along the axes will be $\nu$, but the function as a whole has no limit at $(0,0)$.

**If the limit exists**

If also the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ exists then it has to equal $\nu=\omega$ due to similar reasons in the argument that the limit cannot exist if $\nu\neq\omega$. We can find neighbourhoods of the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$ so that $f(x,y)$ is arbitrarily close to $\nu=\omega$ and these neighbourhoods will still remain in any intersection with a however small neighbourhood of $(0,0)$. So if the limit exists it has to equal the other two.

### Closing remark

Though I somehow feel that my answer here repeats (or maybe elaborates upon) some of the ideas given in the [linked-to-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6482/limits-of-2-variable-functions), and though my analysis is mostly an abstract reformulation of the assumptions the OP gave, I still think and hope it adds a few details and distinctions into cases that others may find interesting too.